# What is the hardness in Decisional Linear Assumption (DLIN)?

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings, group-theory, hardness-assumptions

I had understood what does the DLIN assumption means and [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11282/what-does-the-linear-assumption-over-bilinear-groups-mean) is a related question. But I fail to understand the '***real hardness***' in this problem.

I would be grateful if someone can help me to understand this.

Comment: What is the '***real hardness***' in the DDH problem?